# Ag Grid not displaying data

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ag-grid

I'm trying to implement this [Ag Grid for Angular CLI](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-angularcli/#gsc.tab=0), I've followed each and every steps which they have mentioned in the documentation , but the Value column is empty and not displaying the data. I see no error in console. I tried to debug but no luck. Please help

Please tell me what i doing wrong

**MyGridApplicationComponent**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  GridOptions
} from "ag-grid";
import {
  RedComponentComponent
} from "../red-component/red-component.component";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-grid-application',
  templateUrl: './my-grid-application.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-grid-application.component.css']
})
export class MyGridApplicationComponent {
  private gridOptions: GridOptions;

  constructor() {
    this.gridOptions = < GridOptions > {};
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
        headerName: "ID",
        field: "id",
        width: 200
      },
      {
        headerName: "Value",
        field: "value",
        cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,
        width: 200
      },

    ];
    this.gridOptions.rowData = [{
        id: 5,
        value: 10
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        value: 15
      },
      {
        id: 15,
        value: 20
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**RedComponentComponent**

```js
import {
  Component
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-red-component',
  templateUrl: './red-component.component.html'
})
export class RedComponentComponent {
  private params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's was a stupid mistake, i did not render the params value in the Redcomponent html.

Below code fixed the issue

`<span style="color: red">{{params.value}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

I use a cellRenderer as opposed to a framework

```
columnDef.cellRenderer = KeyRenderer;
columnDef.width = 20;
columnDef.editable = false;
```

and in your renderer you need to render something. The default grid renderers give out html so your need to do likewise. i.e

```
 import { ICellEditor, ICellEditorParams, ICellRenderer, CellEditorFactory } from 'ag-grid/main';

export class KeyRenderer implements ICellRenderer {

    private params: any;
    htmlDiv: HTMLDivElement;

    init(params) {


        this.htmlDiv = document.createElement("div");
        this.htmlDiv.style.width = "100%";
        this.htmlDiv.style.height = "100%";
        this.htmlDiv.style.textAlign = "center";
        this.htmlDiv.style.verticalAlign = "middle";



        if (params.data.IsKeyField) {
            if (params.data.IsKeyField == true) {
                this.htmlDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='/images/icon/key.png' style='height:15px'/>";
            }
        }

    }

    getGui() {
        return this.htmlDiv;
    }

    refresh(params: any): boolean {
        this.params = params;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps